# Composing monad actions with folds

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, monads, reduce

Let's take a function of type `(Monad m) => a -> m a`. For example:

```
ghci> let f x = Just (x+1)
```

I'd like to be able to apply it any number of times. The first thing I tried was

```
ghci> let times n f = foldr (>=>) return $ replicate n f
```

The problem is that it won't work for large `n`:

```
ghci> 3 `times` f $ 1
Just 4
ghci> 1000000 `times` f $ 1
Just *** Exception: stack overflow
```

It doesn't work also the other way:

```
ghci> let timesl n f = foldl' (<=<) return $ replicate n f
ghci> 3 `timesl` f $ 1
Just 4
ghci> 1000000 `timesl` f $ 1
Just *** Exception: stack overflow
```

Actually, what works is using `($!)` strictness operator

```
ghci> let timesStrict n f = foldr1 ((>=>) . ($!)) $ replicate n f
ghci> 3 `timesStrict` f $ 1
Just 4
ghci> 10000000 `timesStrict` f $ 1
Just 10000001
```

Is there a nicer or more idiomatic solution? Or probably a stricter one? I still easily get stack overflows if `f` is a heavy-weight function.

*UPD:* I found that writing `times` in a pointful form does not solve the problem of composing heavy-weight monadic actions neither. This works for f x = Just (x+1) but fails in the real world:

```
times f 0 a = return a
times f i a = (f $! a) >>= times f (i - 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make `f` strict as in

```
f x = let y = x+1 in y `seq` Just y
```

or

```
-- remember to enable -XBangPatterns
f !x = Just (x+1)
```

and leave the rest alone, your code runs in constant space (albeit slowly) even with very large `n`:

```
ghci> times 4000000000 f 3
Just 4000000003
```

Comment: Well, still the same problem if you run more iterations:

ghci> iterateM_n 1000000 (Just . (+1)) 3 \n
Just *** Exception: stack overflow \n
ghci> iterateM_n' 1000000 (+) 0 (Just . (+1)) 3 \n
Just *** Exception: stack overflow \n

Comment: I like using `-XBangPatterns` instead of `seq` :-)  Anyhow, if `f` is strict then there's no need for `>>=!` in my answer.  Since it seems that OP's `f` isn't, this could help.

Comment: Thanks! Accepted. This works with (Just . (+1)) indeed. I still have problems with my actual function, but at least now I see what can help.

Comment: @jetxee Thank you! "How do I make this function strict?" seems like a great followup question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably create some stricter variants of existing functions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
iterate' f !x = x : iterate' f (f x)
ma >>=! f = do !a <- ma; f a
times' n f a = iterate' (>>=! f) (return a) !! n
```

Perhaps your problems stem from the fact that `seq` only evaluates the first argument to WHNF?  If you're working on a complex structure, you may need a deeper `seq`, like [deepseq](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq).

Comment: This solution seems to work well, but not better than timesStrict, so it is not scalable neither. I have to look into deepseq. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
 last $ take n $ iterate (>>= f) $ Just 1
```

But it also overflows the stack on large numbers of `n`. I don't have the time right now to look into it more :-(