# Iteration of a randomized algorithm in fixed space and linear time

Tags: performance, haskell, random, profiling

I used to ask a similar question [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236829/composing-monad-actions-with-folds). Now I'll be more specific. The purpose is to learn a Haskell idiom to write iterative algorithms with monadic results. In particular, this might be useful for implementing all kinds of randomized algorithms, such as genetic algorithms and a like.

I wrote an example program that manifests my problem with such algorithms in Haskell. Its complete source is on [hpaste](http://hpaste.org/fastcgi/hpaste.fcgi/view?id=27398#a27398).

The key point is to update an element randomly (thus the result is in `State StdGen` or some other monad):

```
type RMonad = State StdGen

-- An example of random iteration step: one-dimensional random walk.
randStep :: (Num a) => a -> RMonad a
randStep x = do
  rnd <- get
  let (goRight,rnd') = random rnd :: (Bool, StdGen)
  put rnd'
  if goRight
     then return (x+1)
     else return (x-1)
```

And then one needs to update many elements, and repeat the process many, many times. And here is a problem.  As every step is a monad action (`:: a -> m a`), repeated many times, it's important to compose such actions effectively (forgetting the previous step quickly). From what I learned from my previous quesion [(Composing monad actions with folds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236829/composing-monad-actions-with-folds),  `seq` and `deepseq` help a lot to compose monadic actions. So I do:

```
-- Strict (?) iteration.
iterateM' :: (NFData a, Monad m) => Int -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
iterateM' 0 _ x = return $!! x
iterateM' n f x = (f $!! x) >>= iterateM' (n-1) f 

-- Deeply stict function application.
($!!) :: (NFData a) => (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $!! x = x `deepseq` f x
```

It is certainly better than lazy composition. Unfortunately, it is not enough.

```
-- main seems to run in O(size*iters^2) time...
main :: IO ()
main = do
  (size:iters:_) <- liftM (map read) getArgs
  let start = take size $ repeat 0
  rnd <- getStdGen
  let end = flip evalState rnd $ iterateM' iters (mapM randStep) start
  putStr . unlines $ histogram "%.2g" end 13
```

When I measured time required to finish this program, it appears, that it is similar to O(N^2) with respect to the number of iterations (memory allocation seems to be acceptable). This profile should be flat and constant for linear asymptotics:

[image: quadratic time per update]

And this is how a heap profile looks:

[image: heap profile with -hc]

I assume that such a program should run with very modest memory requirements, and it should take time proportional to the number of iterations. How can I achieve that in Haskell?

The complete runnable source of the example is [here](http://hpaste.org/fastcgi/hpaste.fcgi/view?id=27398#a27398).

Comment: Naïve question : shouldn't a random generator be a comonad instead, since it is a kind of stream ? Not all random generators are states, and I'd rather "extract" a random number, not "return to its state". Your code looks too "imperative" for me.

Comment: @Alex: But System.Random is built-in, while Control.Comonad.Random requires you to install many packages and know what's comonad to find it :|.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "over-linear". Could you explain a bit further what the bad behavior is?

Comment: @Alexandre C.: Shame on me, I don't know what a comonad is, and why Control.Comonad.Random is better in this case? Could you suggest a more "functional" way to write it?

I'd like to preserve consumption of random values one at a time, threading a random generator down the stream, instead of passing an infinite list of randoms, because my real-life stepping function is more complicated than `randStep`. Also I'd like to be able to look into results at some points (say every N iterations).

Comment: @sclv: By over-linear I mean that execution time t is O(N^a) where N is the number of iterations and a > 1. It seems to be the case with a = 2. The good behaviour is a = 1

Comment: @jetxee: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonad-random/0.1.2/doc/html/Control-Comonad-Random.html may be useful to begin with. Comonads are a bit like monads, but with arrows reversed (functions take comonadic arguments and return normal values, and you extract from a comonadic object instead of returning to a monadic object).

Comment: @jextee: The proper term is "super-linear".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Some things to consider:

- Use the [mersenne-random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random-pure64) generator, it is often >100x faster than StdGen

For raw all-out performance, write a custom State monad, like so:

```
import System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64

data R a = R !a {-# UNPACK #-}!PureMT

-- | The RMonad is just a specific instance of the State monad where the
--   state is just the PureMT PRNG state.
--
-- * Specialized to a known state type
--
newtype RMonad a = S { runState :: PureMT -> R a }

instance Monad RMonad where
    {-# INLINE return #-}
    return a = S $ \s -> R a s

    {-# INLINE (>>=) #-}
    m >>= k  = S $ \s -> case runState m s of
                                R a s' -> runState (k a) s'

    {-# INLINE (>>) #-}
    m >>  k  = S $ \s -> case runState m s of
                                R _ s' -> runState k s'

-- | Run function for the Rmonad.
runRmonad :: RMonad a -> PureMT -> R a
runRmonad (S m) s = m s

evalRmonad :: RMonad a -> PureMT -> a
evalRmonad r s = case runRmonad r s of R x _ -> x

-- An example of random iteration step: one-dimensional random walk.
randStep :: (Num a) => a -> RMonad a
randStep x = S $ \s -> case randomInt s of
                    (n, s') | n < 0     -> R (x+1) s'
                            | otherwise -> R (x-1) s'
```

Like so: http://hpaste.org/fastcgi/hpaste.fcgi/view?id=27414#a27414

Which runs in constant space (modulo the `[Double]` you build up), and is some 8x faster than your original.

The use of a specialized state monad with local defintion outperforms the Control.Monad.Strict significantly as well.

Here's what  the heap looks like, with the same paramters as you:

[image]

Note that it is about 10x faster, and uses 1/5th the space. The big red thing is your list of doubles being allocated.

---

Inspired by your question, I captured the PureMT pattern in a new package: [monad-mersenne-random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-mersenne-random-0.1), and now your program becomes this:

- [Using monad-mersenne-random](http://hpaste.org/fastcgi/hpaste.fcgi/view?id=27423)

The other change I made was to worker/wrapper transform iterateM, enabling it to be inlined:

```
 {-# INLINE iterateM #-}
 iterateM n f x = go n x
     where
         go 0 !x = return x
         go n !x = f x >>= go (n-1)
```

Overall, this brings your code from, with K=500, N=30k

- Original: 62.0s
- New:       0.28s

So that is, **220x faster**.

The heap is a bit better too, now that iterateM unboxes.
[image]

Comment: Fantastic results. Thank you, Don. I considered mersenne-random to be premature optimization (and din't try it), and assumed something is wrong with the way I use State or iterateM'. It turns out that the custom monad and mersenne-random-pure64 work very well after all. I'll consider using them. Just a couple of questions: is it essential to {-# UNPACK #-} PureMT and {-# INLINE #-} monad implementation? I didn't notice significant difference without them.

Comment: @jetxee it may not matter in this example, as the monad is not exported from the module anyway.

Comment: I updated the post with two changes: a new monad-mersenne-random package, and a worker/wrapper iterateM.

Answer (score 6):

Importing Control.Monad.State.Strict instead of Control.Monad.State yields a significant performance improvement. Not sure what you're looking for in terms of asymptotics, but this might get you there.

Additionally, you get a performance increase by swapping the iterateM and the mapM so that you don't keep traversing the list, you don't have to hold on to the head of the list, and you don't need to deepseq through the list, but just force the individual results. I.e.:

```
let end = flip evalState rnd $ mapM (iterateM iters randStep) start
```

If you do so, then you can change iterateM to be much more idiomatic as well:

```
iterateM 0 _ x = return x
iterateM n f !x = f x >>= iterateM (n-1) f
```

This of course requires the bang patterns language extension.

Comment: It seems to solve my problem. I'll test it this evening and will probably accept this answer.

Comment: Swapping iterateM and mapM is allowed for this example, but will not work for more complex randomized algorithms (I have GA in mind). But thanks for idea.

Comment: Well, swapping is a mild performance improvement. Control.Monad.State.Strict is a much bigger one. In general, however, its better to avoid DeepSeq and instead structure your functions such that they force evaluation to head normal form, and your data structures such that they are necessarily strict enough already.

Comment: I agree. But if I want to compose a long sequence of non-deterministic computations like `a -> m a`, it turns out that some additional strictness is almost a requirement (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236829/ ). As soon as there is something like `[a] -> m [a]`, there appears `deepseq`. I'd like to know better way to write such code in Haskell.

Comment: You need a strict list type. `data StrictList a = Cons !a !(StrictList a) | Nil`. Then if the head is forced, the whole structure is forced. So if you know you always want your list to be used strictly, use a type that enforces it :-)

Comment: Thank you. I'll positively consider it. As far as I can tell Data.Sequence.Seq is strict too, right?

Comment: It's spine strict, but not element strict. Also, it has vastly different performance characteristics than lists. (Summary -- better asymptotics for many operations, significantly poorer constant factors .)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a small point compared to the other answers, but is your ($!!) function correct?

You define

```
($!!) :: (NFData a) => (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $!! x = x `deepseq` f x
```

This will fully evaluate the argument, however the function result won't necessarily be evaluated at all.  If you want the `$!!` operator to apply the function and fully evaluate the result, I think it should be:

```
($!!) :: (NFData b) => (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $!! x = let y = f x in y `deepseq` y
```

Comment: That won't do anything except burn cycles. It says "Before you evaluate `f x`, make sure that you evaluate `f x`." See here: http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2008/05/bad-strictness.html

Comment: @sclv, thanks for that link.  I would agree that my suggestion is wrong because the questioner's version has similar semantics to $!.

Being pedantic, is `deepseq x x` really the same as `seq x x`?  I would think it says "Before you evaluate `x` to WHNF, fully evaluate `x`".  This may (depending on `x`) do strictly more work than the `seq` version, which is undoubtedly wasteful.  Whether it is useful is another matter.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that with my definition of ($!!) the last function application may remain a thunk. But as long as this thunk as at most one-level "deep", I suppose it is OK. The point is not to force the function application, but to force evaluation of the previous state.