# Pure pseudo-random generators for Haskell with a nice API?

Tags: haskell, random

What are the recommended Haskell packages for pure pseudo-random generators (uniform Doubles)?

I'm interested in a convenient API in the first place, speed would be nice too.

Maybe mwc-random?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard [System.Random](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html) has a pure interface. I would recommend wrapping it in a `State g` (for whatever generator *g* you're using) to avoid threading the state; the [`state`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/late/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html#v%3astate) function makes turning functions like `next` into stateful actions easy:

```
next :: (RandomGen g) => g -> (Int, g)
state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> State s a
state next :: (RandomGen g) => State g Int
```

The [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) package is based on the `State g` interface with pre-written wrappers for the generator functions; I think it's fairly popular.

Note that you can still run actions using this pure interface [on the global RNG](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html#g:3).  MonadRandom has [evalRandIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random.html#v%3aevalRandIO) for the purpose.

I think you could write an (orphan) [RandomGen](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/latest/doc/html/System-Random.html#t%3aRandomGen) instance to use mwc-random with these.

Comment: @ehird What is here the IO free source of randomness that would keep it pure? ECC?

Comment: @JFritsch: Remember, pure doesn't just mean no IO. A pure function must _always_ return the same result given the same arguments. The only "source of randomness" is the generator or _seed_ (`g` in the type signatures).

Comment: @JFritsch: No PRNG consults an external source for each number; you just get the seed from there. You can create values of type `StdGen` (an instance of `RandomGen`) from a seed, and there's a global generator in IO presumably seeded from an external source.

Comment: @ehird for P RNGs you are certainly right. Otherwise "no" is a bit strong :D http://www.sqrtech.com/. Good randomness is an issue in a web2.0 world and IO plays a heavy role in it.

Answer (score 8):

I like the [mersenne-random-pure64](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random-pure64-0.2.0.3) package. For example you can use it like this to generate an infinite lazy stream of random doubles from a seed value:

```
import Data.Word (Word64)
import Data.List (unfoldr)
import System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64

randomStream :: (PureMT -> (a, PureMT)) -> PureMT -> [a]
randomStream rndstep g = unfoldr (Just . rndstep) g

toStream :: Word64 -> [Double]
toStream seed = randomStream randomDouble $ pureMT seed

main = print . take 10 $ toStream 42
```

**using System.Random (randoms)**

You can get a similar output with the builtin `randoms` function, which is shorter and more general (Thanks to ehird for pointing that out):

```
import System.Random (randoms)
import System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64 (pureMT)

main = print . take 10 $ randomdoubles where
  randomdoubles :: [Double]
  randomdoubles = randoms $ pureMT 42
```

**making it an instance of MonadRandom**

After reading about `MonadRandom` i got curious how to get `PureMT` working as an instance of it. Out of the box it doesn't work, because `PureMT` doesn't instantiate `RandomGen`'s `split` function. One way to make it work is to wrap `PureMT` in a `newtype` and write a custom `split` instance for the `RandomGen` typeclass, for which there exists a default `MonadRandom` instance.

```
import Control.Monad.Random
import System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64

getTenRandomDoubles :: Rand MyPureMT [Double]
getTenRandomDoubles = getRandoms >>= return . take 10

main = print $ evalRand getTenRandomDoubles g
  where g = MyPureMT $ pureMT 42


newtype MyPureMT = MyPureMT { unMyPureMT :: PureMT }
myPureMT = MyPureMT . pureMT

instance RandomGen MyPureMT where
  next  = nextMyPureMT
  split = splitMyPureMT

splitMyPureMT :: MyPureMT -> (MyPureMT, MyPureMT)
splitMyPureMT (MyPureMT g) = (myPureMT s, myPureMT s') where
  (s',g'') = randomWord64 g'
  (s ,g' ) = randomWord64 g

nextMyPureMT (MyPureMT g) = (s, MyPureMT g') where
  (s, g') = randomInt g
```

Comment: You can do that for any `RandomGen` (of which `PureMT` is an instance), with `randoms :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => g -> [a]`.

Comment: @ehird oh, didn't know about `randoms`! Updated my answer

Comment: There is also `monad-mersenne-random` http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-mersenne-random built on top of `mersenne-random-pure64`. It has a nice property that it allows to run monadic iteration in constant memory space (see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236442/).

Comment: @sastanin Thanks for pointing me to the related question and `monad-mersenne-random`, gave me some new insights!

Answer (score 2):

A particularly nice package with a pure interface that is also suitable for cryptographic applications and yet maintains a high performance is the [cprng-aes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cprng-aes) package.

It provides two interfaces:  A deterministic pure one using the type classes from System.Random as well as a strong IO interface using the type classes from the Crypto-API package.

As a side note:  I would generally prefer the mersenne-random packages over mwc-random.  They use the original Mersenne Twister algorithm and in my benchmarks outperformed mwc-random by a large factor.