# Generating random vectors with constant stack space

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow, monads, lazy-evaluation

I'm working with the packages [System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random-pure64-0.2.0.3/docs/System-Random-Mersenne-Pure64.html) and [Control.Monad.Mersenne.Random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-mersenne-random-0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Mersenne-Random.html) by Don Stewart which are usually blazingly fast, and are [supposed to help avoid common errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3239837/925978), like using non-strict state monads.

Nevertheless, I managed to write some code that results in a stack overflow for moderately large vectors.

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import Data.Int
import System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64
import Control.Monad.Mersenne.Random

main = do
    let dim = 1000000
        y = evalRandom (U.replicateM dim getInt64) (pureMT 13) :: U.Vector Int64
    putStr $ (show $ U.head y)
```

I'm guessing this must be due to laziness in Vector's `replicateM` implementation, though it's difficult to see since it is implemented using `streams`.

How might I write code that uses  constant stack space to sample large vectors?

Comment: Also, I expected that one of `U.head` and `U.tail` would print without a stack overflow, but this isn't the case. This behavior persists even with (hopefully) lazy boxed vectors, which is even more unexpected to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing was immediately obviously wrong with monad-mersenne-random (didn't look at core one iota) but it's worth noting that everything works when using the state monad:

```
import Control.Monad.State

...

        y      = evalState (U.replicateM dim (state $ \s -> randomInt64 s)) (pureMT 13) :: U.Vector Int64
```

With a result of:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
$ ghc so.hs -fforce-recomp
[1 of 2] Compiling Control.Monad.Mersenne.Random ( Control/Monad/Mersenne/Random.hs, Control/Monad/Mersenne/Random.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
$ ./so
-7188968464842378225
```

EDIT:

Looking at the two monad definitions (`StateT` and `Rand`) it seems the only real difference is in the strictness of the tuple.  So I tried using `Control.Monad.State.Strict` and ah-ha!  The stack overflow returned.  So I'm guessing that buried in Vector's `replicateM` code is something similar to the `foldr` used in the `replicateM` from `base`.  This would explain why you won't want the sequence to be strict.

Comment: Really worth “nothing“, or just worth “noting”?

Comment: Well it's worth nothing if you must use the `Rand` monad, I guess, but I did mean "noting". ;-)