# Pure error handling in Haskell with Either: how to fold with error possibility?

Tags: haskell, exception, error-handling, fold, either

I'm mainly interested in the `Either` monad and all it's uilitites from `Control.Error`. Reading [errors-1.0: Simplified error handling](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/errors-10-simplified-error-handling.html), I got convinced *pure errors* should be kept apart from *IO errors*. This means `error`, `fail`, `exitFailure` are functions whose use should be reduced to the IO monad. Pure computations *can* and *will* create condition errors, but are *deterministic*.

Currently, working with **folds**, I got a situation an element in an array may generate a condition error which makes the whole computation unsatisfiable. For example (using [Data.ConfigFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ConfigFile-1.0.5/docs/Data-ConfigFile.html)):

```
type CPError = (CPErrorData, String)
data CPErrorData = ParseError String | ...
type SectionSpec = String
type OptionSpec = String

instance Error CPError
instance Error e => MonadError e (Either e)

get :: MonadError CPError m => ConfigParser -> SectionSpec -> OptionSpec -> m a


dereference :: ConfigParser -> String -> Either CPError String
dereference cp v = foldr replacer v ["executable", "args", "title"]
 where
  replacer :: String -> Either CPError String -> Either CPError String
  replacer string acc = do
    res <- acc
    value <- get cp "DEFAULT" string
    return $ replace ("${" ++ string ++ "}") value res
```

The situation is: I'm using an acc which has a complex type, just because if a single element isn't found doing the replacement, then the whole value isn't calculable.

My question is: Is this ugly? **Is there a better way of doing this?** I have some nastier utilities of type `EitherT CPError IO String` in the `acc` because of some IO checks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I now understand I was looking into a way to fold a list of composable actions. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236829/composing-monad-actions-with-folds) question, and learned about the [Kleisli](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-) operator:

```
dereferenceValue :: ConfigParser -> String -> Either CPError String
dereferenceValue cp v = do
  foldr (>=>) return (fmap replacer ["executable", "args", "title"]) v
 where
  replacer :: String -> String -> Either CPError String
  replacer string res = do
    value <- get cp "DEFAULT" string
    return $ replace ("${" ++ string ++ "}") value res
```

Probably, this seems a bit like my question, but it feels cleaner. Particularly because of the signature of `replacer`. **It doesn't receive a Monad** as a second parameter and becomes **more useful for other parts of code**.

**EDIT**:

Even easier:

```
dereferenceValue :: ConfigParser -> String -> Either CPError String
dereferenceValue cp v = do
  foldM replacer v ["executable", "args", "title"]
 where
  replacer :: String -> String -> Either CPError String
  replacer res string = do
    value <- get cp "DEFAULT" string
    return $ replace ("${" ++ string ++ "}") value res
```

Conclusion: learn to use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20b%20-%3E%20m%20b%29%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20b%20-%3E%20m%20b)

Answer (score 4):

As you discovered, `foldM` works very nicely here. Your `replacer` function

```
replacer :: String -> String -> Either String String
replacer res string = do
  value <- get cp "DEFAULT" string
  return $ replace ("${" ++ string ++ "}") value res
```

can be further beautified using Applicative as follows

```
replacer :: String -> String -> Either String String
replacer res string =
  replace ("${" ++ string ++ "}") <$> get cp "DEFAULT" string <*> pure res
```