# Is there a type class for fallible fold?

Tags: haskell

Let's say `T` is a type that is an instance of `Foldable`.
If I need to perform a fold that can fail, I can use `foldM` with a function that returns a `Maybe`.

But, what if the fallibility of the fold is inherent to `T` itself? Is there a type class for this?
In other words, is there a type class for types that can be folded, but where fold cannot be defined for all values?

Can this be generalized to other Monads (or other type constructors) other than `Maybe`?

### Update

I'm looking for something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
class FoldableT t where
    type F t :: * -> *
    foldMap  :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> F t m
```

Then `Foldable` would just be a special case of `FoldableT` where `F` is Identity.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: This question makes little sense to me. `Foldable` defines `foldMap`, not `foldM`, and the former is about monoids, not monads. Further, `Maybe m` is a monoid if `m` is. Can you clarify what you actually need?

Comment: I have a sum type that takes a Foldable in one of its constructors, but a non-foldable type on the other.

I can define my own "MaybeFoldable" typeclass with something like `maybeFold :: Monoid m => t m -> Maybe m `, but I was wondering if something like this already exists.

Also, could this be generalized? I could define a typeclass like this with any other type constructor instead of Maybe.

Comment: Could you just do `fmap (foldMap f) myMaybeFoldable`?

Comment: The point is more, why should this be a dedicated type class? How would you _use_ it? What laws would it fulfill? A typeclass only really makes sense if it can be used for writing well-behaved polymorphic code.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984923/pure-error-handling-in-haskell-with-either-how-to-fold-with-error-possibility/23985333

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes this is what I'm trying to figure out

Answer (score 1):

One possibility you may not have considered is to wrap the non-foldable type with something that is trivially foldable:

```
newtype Trivial a = Trivial a
    deriving (Functor)
instance Foldable Trivial where
    foldMap _ _ = mempty
```

Then you can derive `Foldable` on the whole type and it will make the non-foldable branch appear empty.

Comment: The problem with this, is that If I get mempty as the result of the fold, I cannot tell if the fold successfully resulted in mempty, or the fold failed.